# Trimming with array of string

Tags: c#, trim

i want to create a simple program that i have a array of strings and for each string i want to check if it contains specified character, i want to remove it.first of all i replace the specified characters with space and when i tried to trim the spaces it doesn't work 
Here it is my code

```
char[] arr = new char[] {' '};
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    words[i] = words[i].Replace('0', ' ');
    words[i] = words[i].Trim(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove all spaces, instead of `words[i] = words[i].Trim(arr);`, you can use:

```
words[i] = words[i].Replace(" ", string.Empty);
```

Personally, I would do this for your first removal (0) as well:

```
words[i] = words[i].Replace("0", string.Empty); // Remove all "0" characters
words[i] = words[i].Replace(" ", string.Empty); // Remove all spaces
```

Or, even:

```
words[i] = words[i].Replace("0", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Trim()` only removes leading and trailing spaces. It won't remove spaces in the middle of a string. There's really no need to do all that work though. You can make a single call to `Replace()` by calling the [appropriate overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx):

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    words[i] = words[i].Replace("0", "");
```

Comment: +1 for explaining what trim does and why it's the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

and for people who like one-liners:

```
words = words.Select(i => i.Replace("0", "").Replace(" ", "")).ToArray();
```